# How to show /About instead of /Home/About url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to do so without of course changing the underlying architecture since it's just about showing an url.

In fact I still want /Home/About to be valid when user type it but shows up /About instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a new route to your global.asax.

EDIT: Fretje gave you the C# version. I'll give you the VB version:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AboutRoute",
    "About",
    New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "About"}
)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar what's the syntax in this simple case (well I guess it's simple) thanks ?

Comment: You want an example, VB or C#?

Comment: C# thanks so I don't know to whom I should give the right answer ... but since this wasn't in my question I'll give it to you as you answered first :)

Answer (score 3):

Yep, just map a new route to it in the `Application_Start` (more in particular `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)`) method in your global.asax.cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "About", // Route name
    "About", // Url with parameters (no parameters in this case)
    new { controller = "Home", action = "About" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the url rewrite package 2.0 for iis7 and it works very well.
http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: He is using MVC so routing can easily be defined. No need for an external tool.

Comment: thanks but I think solution below is more dynamic and give me more control.